# I am a bit confused on the definition of a graded ring in Eisenbud.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

He defines a graded ring as $R$ together with a direct sum decomposition

$R = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}R_n$

where $R_n$ are abelian groups such that $R_iR_j \subset R_{i+j}$

I understand addition on $R$ i.e. $f,g \in \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}R_n$. Then, $(f+g)(n) = f(n) + g(n)$, but confused about how multipication is defined i.e. what is $fg$?

Comment: Multiplication in a ring $R$ is a map $R \times R \to R$. The only requirement in a graded ring is that it has to restrict to a map $R_i \times R_j \to R_{i+j}$ for all $i, j$

Comment: @math54321 since $R_i \times R_j \rightarrow R_{i+j}$ ,then $(fg)(n) \sum_{i+j = n}f(i)g(j)$?

Comment: Yes $\hspace{0cm}$